# rdlc Expression Error

Tags: rdlc

I am using iif(Field!test1.Value=nothing,"",test1.Value.ColumnName)

It works fine if test1.value is not null. If it is null then i am getting #Error in my report.

Is there something i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

if the value u r getting is a string

```
IIF(Field!test1.Value="","",test1.Value.ColumnName)
```

else compare with 0 like dis

```
 IIF(Field!test1.Value=0,"",test1.Value.ColumnName)
```

try dis.

Answer (score 0):

IIF(Field!test1.Value = "" , "" , test1.Value.ColumnName)

In the above if condition the field test1 will check the value as equal to "" (blank) which is the first part before first comma, id it holds true than the value will be assigned as ""(blank), otherwise the last part of the equation test1.Value.ColumnName

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will throw an error if you try to access 'ColumnName' on something that doesn't exist.

The below [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6268276/2874896) might give some help.

> IIF evaluates all arguments. If any argument generates an error, then
>   the entire function will throw an error, regardless of which of the
>   three arguments should have been returned.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
=Iif(IsNothing(Field!test1.Value),"",test1.Value.ColumnName)
```